# using xmllib2 for C to get an element value

Tags: c, xml

I need to port a small snippet of code from PHP to C that extracts the values of miscellaneous elements that can be in any order for their level in the XML tree. An example XML document is:

```
<book>
    <author>John Smith</author>
    <title>A Marvelous Book</title>
</book>
```

In PHP the code to extract title is:

```
$xmlDoc = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlStr);
$title = $xmlDoc->title;
```

For C I'll be using libxml2 (of which I have no familiarity). So far I have:

```
xmlDoc = xmlReadMemory(xmlStr, strlen(xmlStr), "noname.xml", NULL, 0);
```

Now what? Should I use XPATH to extract title? Seems like overkill...
Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

So what I ended up doing, for example to extract title, is:

```
if (xpathCtx = xmlXPathNewContext(doc)) {
    if (xpathObj = xmlXPathEvalExpression("//title[1]", xpathCtx)) {
        if (nodes = xpathObj->nodesetval) {
            if ((nodes->nodeNr == 1) && (nodes->nodeTab[0]->type == XML_ELEMENT_NODE)) {
                value = xmlNodeGetContent(xpathObj->nodesetval->nodeTab[0]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Yuck!